# dynamic button creation with single refrence

Tags: android

Here i am creating 20 Button dynamically using for loop

exmple

```
for(int i =1 ;i <= 20 ;i++){
Button b = new Button(this);
b.setText(String.valueOf(i));
b.setId(String.valueOf(i));
b.setBackgroudColor(Color.Red);

b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            b.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);


        }
);

}
```

If i select 1st Button color will be changing to green remaining all are red. similarly if i select 2nd Button  1st and 2nd button color will be green and remaining all are red. this is the way it working fine .but my requirement is if i select the any button 2nd time all buttons and previous button which i pressed color should be red. to do that  i am not getting the previous button id's. can any help for this problem

Comment: Are you sure using 20 Buttons is a good choice? Can you use GridView? You can change the backGroundColor as well: http://forums.pragprog.com/forums/152/topics/10301

Comment: These buttons is for to show database record navigation wise. display records by pagination concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hold a reference of the previously pressed button:

```
final Button prevButton;
for(int i =1 ;i <= 20 ;i++){
    Button b = new Button(this);    
    b.setText(String.valueOf(i));
    b.setId(String.valueOf(i));
    b.setBackgroudColor(Color.Red);

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(prevButton != null)
                    prevButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                b.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                prevButton = (Button)v;
            }
    );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure using 20 Buttons is a good choice? 
Can you use GridView? 
You can change the backGroundColor as well: forums.pragprog.com/forums/152/topics/10301

Comment: This is not really an answer, but a comment, which you have already provided.

Comment: These buttons is for to show database record navigation wise. display records by pagination concept. so can't change the requirement.